# How do you use scalamock to mock a class with constructor parameters

Tags: scala, scalamock

I know how to mock a class that has no constructor parameters

e.g.,
`myMock = mock[MockClass]`

However, what do you do if the class has constructor parameters?

More specifically I'm trying to mock the finatra class: `ResponseBuilder`

https://github.com/ImLiar/finatra/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finatra/ResponseBuilder.scala

Comment: (1) `ResponseBuilder` does NOT take constructor parameters. (2) if it did, you could still mock it as `mock[ResponseBuilder]`, the constructor parameters do not matter, (3) it is almost never a good idea to mock builders

Comment: Mocking classes with non-default constructors (so, with parameters) is actually supported by ScalaMock, in the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the test class on github however the answer to this depends on what you want to achieve. You wouldn't mock a class however using [specs2](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/) and [mockito](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.9.5/org.specs2.guide.UseMockito.html) you can spy on it to determine if something has happened this is an example of what you might be trying to achieve.

```
class Responsebuilder(param1: Int, param2: int) {
    def doSomething() { doSomethingElse() }
    def doSomethingElse() { ...
}

class ResponseBuilderSpec extends Specification with Mockito {
    "response builder" should {
        "respond" in {
            val testClass = spy(new ResponseBuilder(1, 3))
            testClass.doSomething()

            there was one(testClass).doSomethingElse()
        }
    }
}
```

One would normally mock traits as dependencies and then inject them into the test class once you defined their behaviour

```
trait ResponseBuilderConfig { def configurationValue: String }

class Responsebuilder(val config: ResponseBuilderConfig, param2: int) {
    def doSomething() { doSomethingElse(config.configurationValue) }
    def doSomethingElse(param: String) { ...
}

class ResponseBuilderSpec extends Specification with Mockito {
    "response builder" should {
        "respond" in {
            val mockConfig = mock[ResponseBuilderConfig]
            mockConfig.configurationValue returns "Test"
            val testClass = spy(new ResponseBuilder(mockConfig, 3))
            testClass.doSomething()

            there was one(testClass).doSomethingElse("Test")
        }
    }
}
```